# How to align data points to date labels on x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created the following chart using `ggplot2`. I'm struggling to get the date labels on the x-axis to be aligned with the actual datapoints in my dataset/chart.

For example, my dataset starts in 2022Q1 (2022-03-31) and ends in 2024Q4 (2024-12-31) but by x axis labels in my chart start in 2022Q2 and end in 2025Q1. Is there a way to fix this so that the 2022Q1 label is aligned to the first point in my dataset and 2024Q4 is aligned to the last point in my dataset?

```
data <- structure(list(date = structure(c(19082, 19173, 19265, 19357, 
19447, 19538, 19630, 19722, 19813, 19904, 19996, 20088, 19082, 
19173, 19265, 19357, 19447, 19538, 19630, 19722, 19813, 19904, 
19996, 20088), class = "Date"), Key = c("GDP Growth", "GDP Growth", 
"GDP Growth", "GDP Growth", "GDP Growth", "GDP Growth", "GDP Growth", 
"GDP Growth", "GDP Growth", "GDP Growth", "GDP Growth", "GDP Growth", 
"Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", 
"Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", 
"Inflation", "Inflation"), Value = c(1.51997911303052, 1.3609508289969, 
1.12382021596744, 0.153357156346878, 0.498498291993229, 0.571752977544741, 
0.637563449287277, 0.679237610448936, 0.705989998933409, 0.723414309351956, 
0.734639392187145, 0.741887403945317, 1.40434784162933, 2.26763925389974, 
1.94887199327987, 1.12177123773538, 1.34973912868682, 1.3151509287165, 
1.33381874039021, 1.34158386354868, 1.34863061253578, 1.35379131133541, 
1.35752118934184, 1.36016559955722)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -24L))

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data %>% {
    ggplot(., aes(date, Value, col = Key)) +
      annotate("rect", xmin = as.Date('2023-01-01'), xmax = as.Date('2024-12-31'), 
               ymin = -Inf,  ymax = Inf, fill = "grey", alpha= 0.3) +
      geom_line(data=subset(., date<=as.Date('2023-01-01')), linewidth = 1, col = '#6d1d26', aes(linetype='dashed')) + 
      geom_line(data=subset(., date>=as.Date('2023-01-01') - months(1)), linewidth = 1, col = '#6d1d26', aes(linetype='solid')) +
      facet_wrap(~Key, nrow = 2, scales = 'free') +
      theme_light() +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%")) +
      guides(col = 'none', linetype = 'none') +
     scale_x_date(breaks = "3 months", limits = c(head(.$date, 1), tail(.$date, 1)),
                 labels = function(x) zoo::format.yearqtr(x, "%Y-Q%q"))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set that in the `breaks` argument of your `scale_x_date()`:

```
data %>% {
  ggplot(., aes(date, Value, col = Key)) +
    annotate("rect", xmin = as.Date('2023-01-01'), xmax = as.Date('2024-12-31'), 
             ymin = -Inf,  ymax = Inf, fill = "grey", alpha= 0.3) +
    geom_line(data=subset(., date<=as.Date('2023-01-01')), linewidth = 1, col = '#6d1d26', aes(linetype='dashed')) + 
    geom_line(data=subset(., date>=as.Date('2023-01-01') - months(1)), linewidth = 1, col = '#6d1d26', aes(linetype='solid')) +
    facet_wrap(~Key, nrow = 2, scales = 'free') +
    theme_light() +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%")) +
    guides(col = 'none', linetype = 'none') +
    scale_x_date(breaks = seq(from = as.Date("2022-03-01"), to = as.Date('2024-12-31'),by = "3 month"), 
                 limits = c(head(.$date, 1), tail(.$date, 1)),
                 labels = function(x) zoo::format.yearqtr(x, "%Y-Q%q")) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
}
```

I've also rotated your x axis labels vertically so we can better see the labels.